# Passing variable/array through several pages in php

Tags: php, arrays, variables, foreach, parameter-passing

my code starts with multiple php arrays with XML data being passed through multiple checkboxes in the following way($i cycles through items in XML doc, values pass specific data in row i that is selected):

```php
$MoneyLine = $event->periods->period[0]->moneyline; //background info
$AwayMoneyLine[] = $MoneyLine->moneyline_visiting;  //background info
<input type='checkbox' name='AwayMoneyLine'   value='$Date[$i];$AwayRotNum[$i];$AwayParticipantName[$i];$ATotalPoints[$i]'/>
```

On my next page, I pass the variables in the following manner, but they are not resulting on the next page.:

```php
if(isset($_POST['AwayMoneyLine'])){  
foreach($_POST['AwayMoneyLine'] as $value) {   
$d = explode(';',$value);    
echo '<input type="hidden" name="hidden[]" value="$d[0];$d[1];$d[2];$d[3];$d[4]">';
```

Here is how I'm attempting to get the data on the next page. Any suggestions on how I can pass the variables through to this page? On the form (also on var_dump of $d), I get $d[0], $d[1], etc. Any help is greatly appreciated!:

```php
foreach($_POST['hidden'] as $value) {  
$f = explode(';',$value);  
echo 'Here is your following bet:';  
echo '<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1" bordercolor="#585858" width=100%>';  
     echo "<tr><td>$e[0]</td><td>$f[0]</td><td>$f[1]</td><td>$f[2]</td><td>$f[3]</td><td>$f[4]</td></tr>";  
}  
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Why dont you put them in the $_SESSION[]?

Comment: Use double quote if you want php to replace your variables with values assigned to this variables in sting, e.g. echo "$myvar"

Comment: @case1352 I'm working on a session fix, but I was wondering if it was possible using the example I had. It's definitely my next option though!

Comment: @Nemoden I'm not sure I understand what you're suggesting to double quote. Could you be more specific?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the code to:

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hidden[]\" value=\"$d[0];$d[1];$d[2];$d[3];$d[4]\">";
```

$d[0];$d[1];$d[2];$d[3];$d[4] will not be printed as you put inside single quote. You should use double quote and escape attributes like type=\"hidden\", name=\"hidden[]\", etc.,

eg:

```
<?php

$name = 'foo';
echo "$name";
echo '<br />';
echo '$name';
?>
```

Output:

```
foo
$name
```

Comment: thanks for your help, I really need to be more careful with my single and double quotes!

Answer (score 0):

```
use $serial=serialize($array);
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"hiddenfield\" value=\"<?php echo$serial; ?>">";
```